# WARNING:  Someone is trying to access a secure resource : /WEB-INF/login.xhtml

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jsf-2, http-status-code-404

I am using Eclipse Indigo for developing my JSF 2.0 web application. I have created a dynamic web project with JSF 2.0 and JSTL 1.2 libraries. There are some Facelet files. The welcome file is `login.xhtml`.

After deploying the project, whenever I run `login.xhtml` in Tomcat 7.0.11, I get the following error in browser:

> **HTTP Status 404**
>   type Status report
>   message
>   description The requested resource () is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/7.0.11

In Eclipse's Tomcat console, I get the following error:

```
**Feb 14, 2012 1:08:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4693 ms
Feb 14, 2012 1:09:14 PM javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet service
WARNING:  Someone is trying to access a secure resource : /WEB-INF/login.xhtml
 remote address is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
 remote host is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
 remote user is null
 request URI is /Test/faces/WEB-INF/login.xhtml
```

`web.xml` is the default one generated by the Eclipse, however I have changed the welcome file name in that.

How is this error caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources in `/WEB-INF` folder are not publicly accessible. That folder should be used exclusively for configuration files (like `web.xml`) and template/include files which you don't want the enduser to be able to download and view.

You need to move the `login.xhtml` file outside `/WEB-INF` folder and change the request URI to `/Text/faces/login.xhtml`.

Comment: ohhhh sorry for my silly but knowledgeable mistake... Thank you.... you saved me...